# ignore neg. values in Rank function VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge file where i want to rank all the values in a column where the value "0" would give me rank one. So far no problems. The main problem that is i also have negative numbers and as long as i have these negative numbers they will always rank "lower" than "0" or any other number.

Is there anyway to exclude the negative numbers from the .Rank function?

I could give them a placeholder number but this defeats the purpose since i want to run this code on several "rankings" and i also need the "real" numbers for other calculations.

Stripped my code some and this is basicly what i run now:

```
Sub test()
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Lista As Range
Set Lista = Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:A100")


For i = 1 To lastrow
    irRanking = WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i,1) 
.Value, Lista, 1)
    Worksheets("Sheet").Cells(i, 4).Value = irRanking
Next i
End Sub
```

Or is there another way doing this, skipping .Rank alltogether?

Also have to add that i know its possible using formulas, but i really need a solution in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are in cells A2:AXX

`=IF($A2>0,MATCH($A2,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$XX>0,$A$2:$A$XX),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF($A$2:$A$XX,">0")))),0),"")`

Comment: Hey Michal, Thanks for the input, this will be a way to go if i vant find a solution. I really want it to be VBA based thought since i only wanna do it when i run the macro and the spreadsheet is slow as it is

Answer (score 0):

you could count the negative values and subtract this total to the rank:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, nNegs As Long
    Dim Lista As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Lista = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If Lista(i, 1) >= 0 Then .Cells(i, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(Lista(i, 1), Lista, 1)
        Next i

        nNegs = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Lista, "<0") ' count negative occurrences
        If nNegs > 0 Then 'if any
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In Lista.Offset(, 3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) ' loop through ranks and correct them by subtratcing the number of negative values
                cell.Value = cell.Value - nNegs
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2692768, any feedback?